# jQuery Sortable List Handles on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm creating a list with handles for sorting. I don't like the aesthetics of having 20 handles visible, so I'm trying to make the handles appear only when the mouse hovers over a list item.

This was my first attempt:

[jsFiddle #1](http://jsfiddle.net/scottb/pk9ch/1/)

As you can see, hovering over items in the list creates a rather jarring movement and misalignment of list items. To fix this, I've created a blank 16px image that I use to replace the handle when it's not visible. It creates a much nicer user experience than hovering, as you can see here:

[jsFiddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/scottb/88BPQ/)

```
$(this).prepend("<img src=http://i.imgur.com/tzGrVLc.png class=\"blank-sprite\" / width=16 height=16 border=0>");
```

The problem is that during sorting the 16px image often disappears, leaving things out of alignment. (I'd post an image but I don't have the reputation.) It doesn't always happen, but seems to happen more frequently when I'm sorting very quickly.

I'd love to know why this happens and how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set position css property of icon element to absolute. This is to give you the idea:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pk9ch/5/)

```
var $icon = $("<span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical\" style=\"display:inline-block\" id=\"handle\" /></span>").css({
            position:'absolute',
            top:$(this).offset().top+5,
            left:$(this).offset().left-10
        });
$(this).prepend($icon);
```

Comment: Thank you! This does fix the positioning problem. However, it feels... jittery and buggy? The sorting doesn't feel as smooth. Any thoughts on why that is and how to fix?